# Why's my cURL POST request returning 200 but failing to parse the payload?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

I've been stuck on this issue where I'm getting a `200` response but when I preview what's being returned on the network tab - I get a weird error saying `Payload is missing or failed to parsetrue`.

When I run `dd(response()->json($response));` - I do see a response payload but why won't that that get returned whenever it's not inside the `dd()`?

Whenever I `dd($response);` I get:

`Payload is missing or failed to parse`

`true`

I've tried numerous ways to run a `foreach(...) {}` to try to parse it that way but to no avail.  What am I doing wrong?

```
           $data = [
                "event"         => "name",
                "id"            => "user id",
                "eventValue"    => "{\"nextEvent\":\"0\",\"otherEvent\":\"0\"}",
                "eventCurrency" => "USD",
            ];

            $curl = curl_init();

            curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                CURLOPT_URL           => "myApiUrl.com,
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS    => json_encode($data),
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER    => array(
                    "content-type" => "application/json",
                    "authentication" => env("API_KEY")
                ),
            ));
            

            $response = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close($curl);

          // dd(response()->json($response));


            return response()->json($response);
```

Comment: Sounds like you may be getting that message from your API response. It's possible that it does not like your `eventValue` json, but it's hard to tell

Comment: what is the var_dump($response) showing?

Comment: Just show us a `dd($response);`

Comment: @RiggsFolly the result of `dd($response);` is there in my original post.

Comment: @AgamemnonKatradis it's there on my original post :).

Comment: You said that was the output from `dd(response()->json($response));` do a simple `dd($response);`

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes, I'm getting the same output when doing both

Comment: Then as said above, that appears to be the API reporting an issue with the data you pass to it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should change

```
"eventValue"    => "{\"nextEvent\":\"0\",\"otherEvent\":\"0\"}",
```

to

```
"eventValue"    => {"nextEvent":0,"otherEvent":0}",
```

You have to pass the `eventValue` as a json array itself.